# Определить, есть ли в строке изображения

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть переменная `$text` в которой находится текст в виде html содержимого. 
Вопрос: Как определить есть ли в нем изображение ( тег  ) ?

Comment: `strpos($text,'<img') !== false`

Answer (score 4):

Самое простое, что сразу приходит в голову - это написать что то вида

```
if (strpos($text, '<img') !== false) {
 ...
}
```

но это плохой способ. Данная подстрока может быть, но не являться тегом. Также тег может быть,  но записан так  '< img'.

Поэтому, самый надежный способ - это [полноценно парсить](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Где то так

```
$html = str_get_html($text);

// найдем все картинки
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// найдем все ссылки
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Есть правда ещё один случай - это когда картинка генерируется javascript'ом. Тут все немного сложнее. Но если сильно-сильно нужно, то можно использовать [selenium+phantomjs](https://github.com/yatnosudar/PHP-WebDriver-Phantomjs-Selenium/blob/master/example.php). Настроить конечно будет немного сложновато, но работать будет достаточно надежно.

Comment: это мне напомнило проект отстрела комаров лазером. Вероятно есть случаи, когда оправдано, но...

Comment: комары и лазеры бывают разные.

Comment: Абсолютно поддерживаю часть ответа про полноценный парсинг. Вариант с strpos обломается на банальном варианте <!--<img src="/image.jpg" alt="Изображение в комментарии">-->(ложноположительное срабатывание), впрочем как и на варианте <IMG src="/image.jpg">(ложноотрицаиельное срабатывание), а скорее всего и на <imgOmgHTML5Rocks>(ложноположительное срабатывание). По этому еще раз: если нужно найти что угодно в HTML(XML/JSON/etc) - используйте библиотеки, пожалуйста, не изобретайте велосипед.

Comment: я собственно об этом и говорю

Answer (score 0):

**1 Вариант:**

```
mb_substr_count // Возвращает количество вхождений подстроки

<?php echo 
   mb_substr_count("Это просто проверка", "то"); // выведет на экран 2
?>
```

т.е. если сделать так:

```
$count = mb_substr_count($text, '<img'); // получим количество вхождений img
```

Проверку думаю сами сможете сделать, типа:

```
if($count == 0){
   ...
}
```

**2 Вариант:**

```
if(strpos($text,'<img') !== false){
...
}
```

Выбирайте.

Comment: Вариант strpos будет куда быстрее и менее ресурсоемкий.

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan я два варианта предложил, тут уже кто как хочет)

Comment: В момент написания моего комментария 2 варианта не было.